# Persistent http connection from Java server

Tags: java, android, spring, http, push-notification

I want to create a persistent connection between Java spring server and Android client.

What I need is sort of a push mechanism with a persistent (long-lived HTTP) connection that will stream all the information from server to the client once they are available.

Are there any available frameworks that would support that, Java Spring preferably. Tutorials or documents that will help me implementing this.

Comment: The best you'll get is something along the lines of comet/long polling/reverse ajax with a keep-alive connection, which keeps the underlying TCP connection alive across requests. There is no "connection" in HTTP.

Comment: That is a little untrue, in that opening a request for chunked data creates a persistent connection

Comment: I need to create restful server and a Android client (not a web client, but Android native app) that will connect to this server and wait for a response, so HTML/Ajax is not for me. And if I understand well comet is for web solutions only, am I right?

Comment: Comet is more a technique doing the communication pattern you are asking for. And this is not that "restful".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) to learn about the general ways to accomplish that.

Some example technologies are:

- [Google App Engine Channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html)
- [HTML5 Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets)
- [Blaze DS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS)

Answer (score 0):

Long-lived HTTP connections and WebSockets are generally more suited to web apps when it comes to 'push'.

If you don't mind some work on the server side, a persistent socket is definitely the most battery friendly way.

Here's a good start: http://devtcg.blogspot.com/2009/01/push-services-implementing-persistent.html