# Android persistent HttpClient connection

Tags: android, httpclient

Would it be possible to setup an HttpClient such that on a website that updates periodically, perhaps due to AJAX, the resulting changes would be captured by the HttpClient. Similar to keeping a connection to a website alive, and if there were an update, the HttpClient would send the updated response to a listener of some type.  I feel as if there is an obvious answer to my question, but I just haven't found it because I may have some of my terminology wrong...

This is just an example snippet of how I usually set up a connection:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

Comment: Basically what you are asking is to mock a web browser running JS. Don't think that's possible with HttpClient.

Comment: I believe that's essentially what I'm looking for.  What I'm using temporarily is a WebView without showing the View.  To elaborate: I have a WebView object in a Service, and inject it with javascript to get the source.  Unfortunately, doing it this way leaks the context of the ActivityThread, which doesn't allow the Activity front end to die. >.<; (This is my main problem..)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not think keeping a constant connection open to your site would be the best solution. Why don't you just poll every once in awhile?

Comment: Hello Jack! Thanks for the welcome! (Long-time lurker) The reason I don't poll is because the initial load-in amount is quite large. It does not make sense to re-poll.  I should also note, that on the response, the page isn't fully loaded in due to it being dynamically updated.  Which, is why I would like to have the connection be notified.

Comment: So if you have 20,000 users, you will maintain 20,000 connections at all times?

Comment: I don't own the website; it's essentially for a Social Network chat who refuses to offer an API.  (For what reason, baffles me, but it's how they want.. :/ )

Comment: Hrmm.... interestingly enough I was just browsing around looking at google cloud services, and found http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#intro. Might not be what you need, but its worth a look.

Comment: I wish I had access to the actual code of the website instead of being forced to use their pre-defined way of doing things.. Unfortunately, I won't be able to do that..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584475/persistent-http-connection-from-java-server